# updating status using oauth on twitter with coldfusion

Tags: twitter, coldfusion, oauth, status

I generated my OAuth signature using twitter's own tool at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update How do I use the "signature base string" and "authorization header" with CFHTTP to post a new status on my own twitter account. I'm not trying to access anyone else's account, just need to be able to post status updates to my own account. Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I guess there's no easy way of doing this.

I wonder: Why is that this OAuth protocol is so complicated? "A mad men throws a stone into the well, 40 wisemen cannot get it out" it feels like...

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother writing it yourself, use this: http://monkehtweet.riaforge.org/  its great I have used it many times for twitter integration.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write it yourself, you'll have to follow the instructions documented on https://dev.twitter.com/docs.

A signature is a serialization and encoding of all your request values in combination with a signing key. It's all very well documented at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature

You'll need the hmac-sha1 encoding to create a valid signature. If you're not using coldfusion 10, you'll need something like this: [HMAC SHA1 ColdFusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959972/hmac-sha1-coldfusion)